# How to change function of Django source in our code

Tags: python, django, django-views

I want all inactive users also can login,
in dajngo/contrib/auth/backends.py line 51 we have:

```
def user_can_authenticate(self, user):
    """
    Reject users with is_active=False. Custom user models that don't have
    that attribute are allowed.
    """
    is_active = getattr(user, 'is_active', None)
    return is_active or is_active is None
```

it should return `True` instead of `is_active or is_active is None` but i don't want change Django source.
this is my login view:

```
def login(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == "POST":
            phone_number = request.POST["phone_number"]
            password = request.POST["password"]
            user = authenticate(request, username=phone_number, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login_auth(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect("/account/")
            else:
                ctx = {'msg_bad':'wrong password or phonenumber!'}
        else:
            ctx = {}                
    else:
        return redirect("/account/")
    return render(request, "account/login.html", ctx)
```

is there way to solve this problem by returning True `user_can_authenticate` in this view or if we do that, it also work in account page and others ? or should do  that solution everywhere ?

Comment: Try setting `user.is_active = True` before calling `login_auth`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the [**`AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS`** setting [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#authentication-backends) to the [**`AllowAllUsersModelBackend`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.backends.AllowAllUsersModelBackend):

```
# settings.py

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.AllowAllUsersModelBackend'
]
```